# Referencing an URL: Change "Retrieved from" to "Available here"

Tags: natbib, babel, apa-style

I have some URLs in my references. When using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, "Retrieved from [some URL]" turns into "Zugriff auf [some URL]", e.g.

[image: German translation of "Retrieved from"]

I would like to change "Zugriff auf" into "Verfügbar unter". How can I do that?
Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[tocbib, natbibapa, nosectionbib]{apacite}
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{\ignorespaces}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{A,
    title = {dplyr: A Grammar of Data Manipulation ({Version} 0.3.0.2)},
    author = {Hadley Wickham and Romain Francois},
    year = {2014},
    type = {\bibcomputersoftware},
    url = {http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dplyr}
    }
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{A}.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{test} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: If all hyperlinks are supposed to use black, it's simpler to specify the following color-related option: `allcolors=black`.

Comment: @Mico thx for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition is contained in the file `german.apc` and is given as

```
\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Zugriff auf\ }%
```

so you just need to issue a similar `\renewcommand` *after* `\begin{document}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[tocbib, natbibapa, nosectionbib]{apacite}
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{\ignorespaces}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{A,
    title = {dplyr: A Grammar of Data Manipulation ({Version} 0.3.0.2)},
    author = {Hadley Wickham and Romain Francois},
    year = {2014},
    type = {\bibcomputersoftware},
    url = {http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dplyr}
    }
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Verf\"ugbar unter\ }

\citet{A}.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{test} 

\end{document}
```

Note that the file also contains

```
\renewcommand{\BRetrieved}[1]{Zugriff am {#1} auf\ }%
```

which is used when a `lastchecked` field is provided.
There is also

```
\renewcommand{\BAvailFrom}{Verf\"ugbar unter\ }%
```

but the documentation says this has been superceded by `\BRetrievedFrom`.