# How to remove a dot with apacite after howpublished

Tags: bibliographies, apacite, url

I´m writing a paper for my university, my citation style is APA 6, so i´m using `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` i also use `\usepackage{apacite}`. For some of my literature i need to provide the url, which i do by using the entry `howpublished={accessed on 19.03.2020 from \url{https://www. . . .  .com}` in my `.bib` file. The problem is, that in my reference list appears a dot after every url, which i do not want there. I suspect that the dot appears because of the howpublished field. Is there any way to remove the dot?

Here is mwe:

```
\documentclass[parsikip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Schaltet auf erweiterten Zeichensatz um
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Setzt die Zeichenkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % Deutsche Sprachumgebung
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} % Paket für Anführungszeichen
\usepackage{microtype}      % u.a. optischer Randausgleich
\usepackage{color}          % Farbiger Text
%\usepackage{calc}          % Ermöglicht einfache Rechnungen in Längenangaben
%\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}        % Kopf- und Fusszeilen 
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\parindent1.5cm                % Verhindert den Einzug der ersten Zeile eines neuen Absatzes

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EigenePakete
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paralist}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,draft = false,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur_ab.bib}
@book{jim,
    title={{JIM-Studie 2018. Jugend, Information, Medien. Basisuntersuchung zum Medienumgang 12-bis 19-J{\"a}hriger}},
    author={{Medienpädagogischer Forschungsverbund Südwest}},
    year={2018},
    howpublished={Abgerufen am 25.02.2020 von \url{https://www.mpfs.de/fileadmin/files/Studien/JIM/2018/Studie/JIM2018_Gesamt.pdf}}
}
\end{filecontents}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Pagestyle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}}
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries}  % Schaltet in Überschriften auf Roman-Schriften um
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\textsc}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Eigene commands
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\anf}[1]{\glqq{}#1{}\grqq{}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}%
    \renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}%
    }

\newcommand{\zittext}[2]{\cite[S. #2]{#1}}
\newcommand{\hervor}[2]{\cite[S. #2, Hervorheb. i.O.]{#1}}





\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\cite{jim}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Literaturverzeichnis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Referenzen}

%%%%%%% Literaturverzeichnis
\newgeometry{left=31mm, right=31mm, top=23mm, bottom=22mm}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{literatur_ab} 
\newpage 


\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please provide also your `literatur_ab.bib` file with an example reference? Btw, you need to load the `geometry` package for your MWE to work. Or simply remove the `\newgeometry` command in the end.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot. 

The references look like this:

@book{jim,
 title={{JIM-Studie 2018. Jugend, Information, Medien. Basisuntersuchung zum Medienumgang 12-bis 19-J{\"a}hriger}},
 author={{Medienpädagogischer Forschungsverbund Südwest}},
 year={2018},
 howpublished={Abgerufen am 25.02.2020 von  \url{https://www.mpfs.de/fileadmin/files/Studien/JIM/2018/Studie/JIM2018_Gesamt.pdf}}
}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the wrong use of the field `howpublished`.

You should rather use

```
url={https://www.mpfs.de/fileadmin/files/Studien/JIM/2018/Studie/JIM2018Gesamt.pdf},
urldate={25.02.2020}
```

and redefine the language parameters (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294672/referencing-an-url-change-retrieved-from-to-available-here) for instance):

```
\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Abgerufen unter\ }%
\renewcommand{\BRetrieved}[1]{Abgerufen am {#1} unter\ }%
```

Btw: Your MWE is not a *minimal* working example.

This version is much shorter (maybe still too long). I have changed some other minor things also.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Schaltet auf erweiterten Zeichensatz um
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Setzt die Zeichenkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % Deutsche Sprachumgebung
%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%\usepackage{breakurl}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur_ab.bib}
@book{jim,
    title={{JIM-Studie 2018. Jugend, Information, Medien. Basisuntersuchung zum Medienumgang 12-bis 19-Jähriger}},
    author={{Medienpädagogischer Forschungsverbund Südwest}},
    year={2018},
    url={\url{https://www.mpfs.de/fileadmin/files/Studien/JIM/2018/Studie/JIM2018Gesamt.pdf}},
    urldate={25.02.2020}
}
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\BRetrieved}[1]{Abgerufen am {#1} unter\ }%
\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Zugriff auf\ }%

\cite{jim}


%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Referenzen}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{literatur_ab} 


\end{document}
```

Please read the `apacite` [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/apacite?lang=de), especially the context of Table 3.

Comment: Ok, @luki was quicker (his edit occuring during me writing).

Comment: Also, ```lastchecked``` seems to be the better option as @luki writes.

Comment: It seems we had the same idea at the same time. Good point to also redefine the `\BRetrieved` and `\BRetrievedFrom` macros.

Comment: The contents of the `url` field should usually *not* be wrapped in an additional `\url{...}` command. `url={https://www.mpfs.de/fileadmin/files/Studien/JIM/2018/Studie/JIM2018Gesamt.pdf},` is usually better than `url={\url{https://www.mpfs.de/fileadmin/files/Studien/JIM/2018/Studie/JIM2018Gesamt.pdf}},`.

Comment: Yes, of course. I copied it from @Lukas and overlooked it (in my mwe -- in the first code I had already changed it). Have changed it in the mwe of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `\bibnodot{.}` at the end of the `howpublished` field:

```
@book{jim,
 title={{JIM-Studie 2018. Jugend, Information, Medien. Basisuntersuchung zum Medienumgang 12-bis 19-J{\"a}hriger}},
 author={{Medienpädagogischer Forschungsverbund Südwest}},
 year={2018},
 howpublished={Abgerufen am 25.02.2020 von \url{https://www.mpfs.de/fileadmin/files/Studien/JIM/2018/Studie/JIM2018_Gesamt.pdf}\bibnodot{.}}
}
```

For this to work you need to load the `apacdoc` package in your preamble.

Note, the [`apacite` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf) suggests to better use the `url` and `lastchecked` field in your use case.

```
@book{jim,
 title={{JIM-Studie 2018. Jugend, Information, Medien. Basisuntersuchung zum Medienumgang 12-bis 19-J{\"a}hriger}},
 author={{Medienpädagogischer Forschungsverbund Südwest}},
 year={2018},
 url = {https://www.mpfs.de/fileadmin/files/Studien/JIM/2018/Studie/JIM2018_Gesamt.pdf},
 lastchecked = {25.02.2020}
}
```

Comment: As @hh93 states in his answer you can redefine the `\BRetrieved` and `\BRetrievedFrom` macros to meet your requirements.